# How to rename XML file with xslt. My code is

Tags: xml, xslt

"I want to rename xml files. like old.xml to new.xml with xslt but my code not working please check.

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('file:///d:/123/xslt_path.html')//@path">
  <xsl:variable name="aa" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="aaa" select="concat('file:///', $aa)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ajeet_1" select="iri-to-uri(replace($aaa, '\\', '/'))"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ajeet_coll" select="collection(concat($ajeet_1, '/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'))"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$ajeet_coll">
    <xsl:if test="//citation=''">
      <xsl:variable name="hhhh" select="'file:///d:/123/list_of_files.html'"/>
      <xsl:result-document href="{$hhhh}">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()], '%20', ' ')"/>
        <xsl:text>Citation Tag Empty</xsl:text>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="//citation">
      <xsl:variable name="aa1" select="node()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="jaanam" select="replace(replace($aa1, '([^&lt;&gt;]+) : ([^&lt;&gt;]+)', '$1'), ' ', '_')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="jaanam1" select="concat(replace(tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()], '%20', ' '), '')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document($jaanam)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: give more details about what contains in "file:///d:/123/xslt_path.html"  and what you contains in "file:///d:/123/list_of_files.html"

Comment: xslt_path.html:-
d:\2017\working\003_March\2017_03_08
file:///d:/123/list_of_files.html
write error

Comment: While it may be possible, XSLT is a special-purpose language designed really to do one thing: transform XML content. Consider a general-purpose language (Java, PHP, Python) that can iterate and run OS filesystem changes like renaming files much more easily.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="document('file:///d:/xslt_path.html')//@path">
<xsl:variable name="ajeet_1" select="iri-to-uri(concat('file:///', replace(., '\\', '/')))"/>
<xsl:variable name="ajeet_coll" select="collection(concat($ajeet_1, '/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'))"/>
<xsl:variable name="hhhh" select="'file:///d:/list_of_files.html'"/>
<xsl:result-document href="{$hhhh}">
<xsl:for-each select="$ajeet_coll">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="//citation=''">
<xsl:text>Citation Tag Empty :    </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="replace(tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()], '%20', ' ')"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;    </xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:if test="//citation!=''">
<xsl:variable name="aa1" select="node()"/>
<xsl:variable name="citation" select="//citation/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="jaanam">
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[position() ne last()]" separator="/"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('/', replace(normalize-space(replace($citation, '([^:]+)', '$1')), ' ', '_'), '.xml')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:result-document href="{$jaanam}">
<xsl:copy-of select="$aa1"/>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not rename file in xslt but you can create new document as per your requirement

change this

```
    <xsl:if test="//citation=''">
  <xsl:variable name="hhhh" select="'file:///d:/123/list_of_files.html'"/>
  <xsl:result-document href="{$hhhh}">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()], '%20', ' ')"/>
    <xsl:text>Citation Tag Empty</xsl:text>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:if>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="hhhh" select="'file:///d:/123/list_of_files.html'"/>
            <xsl:result-document href="{$hhhh}">
                <xsl:for-each select="$ajeet_coll">
                    <xsl:if test="//citation=''">
                        <xsl:value-of select="replace(tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()], '%20', ' ')"/>
                        <xsl:text>Citation Tag Empty</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:result-document>
```

because it cause possible error due to repeatation of missing citation.

and change this

```
<xsl:if test="//citation">
      <xsl:variable name="aa1" select="node()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="jaanam" select="replace(replace($aa1, '([^&lt;&gt;]+) : ([^&lt;&gt;]+)', '$1'), ' ', '_')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="jaanam1" select="concat(replace(tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()], '%20', ' '), '')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document($jaanam)"/>
    </xsl:if>
```

to

```
 <xsl:for-each select="$ajeet_coll">
        <xsl:if test="//citation!=''">
            <xsl:variable name="aa1" select="node()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="jaanam" select="replace(replace($aa1, '([^&lt;&gt;]+) : ([^&lt;&gt;]+)', '$1'), ' ', '_')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="jaanam1" select="concat(replace(tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()], '%20', ' '), '')"/>
            <xsl:result-document href="{$jaanam1}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$aa1"/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

it may solve your problem with some changes.